# Get all parent associations for children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am doing the below to get all photos that are tagged with the same tag. What I also want to get is a list of the Albums in which those photos appear.

```
@photos = Photo.tagged_with(@tag)
```

I've tried doing the following but it fails.

```
@albums  = @photos.albums
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@photos is not a singular object, it will return an array of ActiveRecord objects, so you can't do @photos.albums. Assuming there's a one-to-many relationship between the two models, then you have to get each photo then get the albums associated with it.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that.  I just thought there would be a convenience method way of achieving this rather than looping through each one grabbing the albums?

Comment: If you're worried about performance, then you can improve it by using two methods, the first one is to handle n + 1 issue, and after that, you can use Redis to cache the records and fetch them faster. But I don't see another way to get the records without looping.

Comment: Ok, I've done it via a loop.  I just thought there may be a better way. Not necessarily performance wise but simpler in amount of code.  Thanks anyway.